# Spring Integration - Add info at filter with XmlValidatingMessageSelector DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Better explain.

What i want is a validation xml in DSL, that apply one or other xsd depending on one of the fields of the xml.

At now look like this:

Read from a MongoDB -> Split in the files the JSON have -> trying to validate.
But what i want to pass as a parameter is the same XML, not the "classpath:validation.xsd".

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(configurationInbound(factory))
                .split(Configuration.class,m->m.getFiles().values())
                .filter(new XmlValidatingMessageSelector(commonResources.getResource("classpath:validation.xsd"),
                        SchemaType.XML_SCHEMA))
```

Is any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is a bit not clear, but let me guess:

You want to use an XSD resource from the message passing through the flow, not statically configured on the mentioned `XmlValidatingMessageSelector`.

If it is that, then unfortunately that is how this `XmlValidatingMessageSelector` is designed.

As a solution I suggest to implement your own `DynaicXmlValidatingMessageSelector` with some copied logic from the existing `XmlValidatingMessageSelector` and create an `XmlValidator` in the `accept()` method on the fly based on the incoming message.

Comment: Sorry my poor expresion. That was what i was looking for. A url from a local XSD in a field of the XML.
I'm going to continue where you told me.
Thanks